# How to maintain unique login in windows form application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am developing a winform application in which user's login is validated through  ms sql server 2000 database.When user entry its user name and password, application checks its exists in user table or not.

Now my requirement is if a user already login through one system it should not log in through another system.

if solution like make entry in database about status of user like on successful log in mark user status is true and on closing application mark false , then in the case of network or hardware failure or system exception.

so, please suggest me a optimal solution .

Answer (score 0):

You should use timeout. the successful log in is stored in status table with datetime and detect whether user is idle for timeout duration then mark false.